# File Copy failing using Puppet File resource

Tags: puppet, rhel6, puppetmaster

I am trying to copy files using file resource . My code is as follows:

```
node 'Node-002' {
 file { "/root/helloworld.txt":
 ensure => file,
 owner  => "root",
 group  => "root",
 mode   => "0644",
 source  => "puppet://modules/templates/${fqdn}/hosts.erb",
}
}
```

But it is failing with the following error

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[Node-002]/File[/root/helloworld.txt]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///modules/templates/Node-002.example.com/hosts.erb
```

The template location is as follows:

```
  ls -l /apps/wps/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/templates/Node-002.example.com/hosts.erb
 -rw-r--r-- 1 puppet puppet 462 Jul 20 02:13 /apps/wps/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/templates/Node-002.wiley.com/hosts.erb
```

Even if I give the full path in the `source` parameter , it is failing with the same error.

I am using Puppet 4.5.4

Please suggest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your module(s) don't appear to conform to the standard directory structure. With a source URL of `puppet:///modules/foo/bar.txt`, Puppet will be looking for `${codedir}/environments/production/modules/foo/files/bar.txt`. Static files should be in a `files` subdirectory within your module. Templates should be in a `templates` subdirectory within your module and referenced in a `file` resource with `content => template('foo/bar.erb')`. There seems to be some confusion with you using an ERB template as a source which won't get processed in any way.

See https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_fundamentals.html for how your modules should be structured.

Comment: Thanks bodgit. It worked .  I will remain ever grateful to you. You helped a lot

Comment: One more query..Instead of putting under modules folder can I copy it under some directory named scripts and put it under ${codedir}/environments/production  and access it using source  => "puppet://scripts/hosts.sh",

Comment: Yes, you can add custom mount points to the Puppet fileserver, see https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.5/reference/file_serving.html.

Comment: This file is missing . Do i Need to create the file manually at /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/fileserver.conf ?

Comment: It worked for me. Tried creating /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/fileserver.conf and defined the scripts directory inside it